# Addingtimepoints in database ANYLOGIC

Tags: anylogic

In my anylogic database I want to insert time points (insteads of dates, so 16:00:00 instead of 24/05/2022 16:00) but somehow I can not get it done, perhaps it is even not possible? I already tried TIME as type and time, but I've no clue how to add timepoints in the table, when I add for example 03:00:00 the table value stays empty (see figure)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible afaik.

Use a String and convert your times between the String and `java.util.LocalTime` formats using `LocalTime.parse(String)` or similar.

PS: You should use `java.util.LocalTime` for pure times, not `Date`